# Why is the master branch not generated automatically?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have created an empty project on Gitlab.

Then, I have cloned the repository on my local computer:

```
$ git clone git@myserver.com:myname/projet6.git
$ cd projet6
```

Now, I want to create a branch:

```
git checkout -b dev
```

I have created some files and finally:

```
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "v1"
$ git push origin dev
```

I can see my files in Gitlab but Gitlab does not show a master branch, only branch dev.
Now I can push my changes, which I could not do beforehand. However, pushing to `master` remains impossible.

I want to use the master branch later on and because of that I had to create a file at the beginning of the git history in order to create the master branch.

My Question is: Why is the master branch not generated by default?

Comment: master branch is not required, if you have nothing to store in master, what it should to store?

Comment: you always can to do: `git checkout -b master; git push origin master` from dev branch

Comment: In fact what i want to do is to merge on master branch when i want to deploy files on production server

Comment: just merge it before the push.

Comment: I get this error: error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to git@myserver:myname/projet.git

Comment: `git checkout master; git merge dev && git push origin master`

Comment: This will give me the same result than a merge request + merge in gitlab?